# How to detect a fontawesome icon in a PDF using iText7

Tags: excel, powershell, pdf, itext, itext7

I have several thousand PDFs that I am using Powershell and iText7 to process, exporting the text of the PDFs to Excel. The PDFs are generated from HTML -- they are **not** coming from a fillable form. Some vital information is captured with "checkboxes" and "radio buttons" that are actually FontAwesome icons (\f14a for the checkbox, \f111 with a font-weight of 900 for the radio button). The icons are added to the HTML with CSS ::before markup. They show up fine in the PDF, but in my output they are unrecognized as characters (in the Powershell console they appear as small empty rectangles, and in Excel, as small rectangles with a question mark inside them).

Here is the CSS for the selected radio button in the original HTML:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label.ReplaceWithIcon:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    content: "\f111";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Here is the CSS for the checkbox in the original HTML:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.ReplaceWithIcon:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    content: "\f14a";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Is there any way to detect which icon is being used? I don't need the icon to show up in the output -- I just need to know which one was detected. In addition, for the radio button one, I need to know what the font-weight is. (Selected is indicated by font-weight: 900 in the original HTML.)

Comment: Both your values are from Unicode *Private Use Range*:  - `` (U+F111,  *Private Use*) and `` (U+F14A,  *Private Use*). You can't expect that your console/terminal font contains suitable glyphs. Use _standard_ Unicode, e.g. `✓` (U+2713,  *Check Mark*).

Comment: When you override an existing text extraction strategy, do you get a recognizable font name? Also, are those *FontAwesome icons* the only characters extracted as private use area code points? Then you can apply a simple search&replace after extraction before further processing...

Comment: @mkl I'm not quite sure what you mean by overriding an existing text extraction strategy.  For your second question, those icons are probably the only private use area characters.

Comment: *"I'm not quite sure what you mean by overriding an existing text extraction strategy."* - Your task is *exporting the text of the PDFs*, i.e. text extraction. For text extraction with iText 7 you use a text extraction strategy (as you don't show your code, I cannot show where you do). Thus, you can implement special text extraction behavior by creating your own text extraction strategy, probably by deriving from an existing one.

Comment: *"For your second question, those icons are probably the only private use area characters. "* - Then why don't you simply search the text string you get from a PDF for '\uf111' and '\uf14a' and handle them appropriately?

Comment: @mkl Thanks! I was trying to match on '\f111' rather than

Comment: @mkl I didn't have the "u" in "\uf111".

Comment: Great that it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment by @mkl, I got this to work by matching on "\uf111" and "\uf14a".